# Powershell with SQL script issue

Tags: sql, powershell

I have this script in powershell and after executing this $scon.Open() code it successfully works. Meaning, it gets the data successfully.

```
$sQry = "SELECT Id, QuoteId, CreateTime, XML FROM dbo.QuoteUpload WHERE year(CreateTime) = " + $sYear
```

Now my task is to get the records from yesterday. So, I changed my script to these…

1. $sQry = "SELECT Id, QuoteId, CreateTime, XML FROM dbo.QuoteUpload WHERE CreateTime >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0) AND CreateTime < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0)"
2. $sQry = "SELECT Id, QuoteId, CreateTime, XML FROM dbo.QuoteUpload WHERE DATEDIFF(day,CreateTime ,GETDATE()) = 1"

And when I executed my powershell script, it gets stuck to this code $scon.Open() and not working.
Please help.

This is my full code: The error is in $sQry when executing $scon.Open().

---

```
clear-host
$sYear = read-host "Enter XML year date: "

Function Execute-SQL {
    Param(
        [string]$sconstring
    )
    Process
    {
        Write-host ("1")
        $scon = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        $scon.ConnectionString = "$sconstring"
        $cmd = $scon.CreateCommand()
        $cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
        $cmd.Connection = $scon

        Write-host ("2")
        #prod
        #this script is working in the server
        #$sQry = "SELECT Id, QuoteId, CreateTime, XML FROM dbo.QuoteUpload WHERE year(CreateTime) = " + $sYear
        
        #these scripts are NOT working in the server
        #$sQry = "SELECT Id, QuoteId, CreateTime, XML FROM dbo.QuoteUpload WHERE CreateTime >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0) AND CreateTime < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0)"
        #$sQry = "SELECT Id, QuoteId, CreateTime, XML FROM dbo.QuoteUpload WHERE DATEDIFF(day,CreateTime ,GETDATE()) = 1"
        
        $strdtTime = Get-Date -UFormat "%m%d%Y" 
        $strDay = Get-Date -UFormat "%d"
        [int]$strDay = [int]$strDay - 1

        $strMonth = Get-Date -UFormat "%m"
        [int]$strMonth = $strMonth

        $strYear = Get-Date -UFormat "%Y"
        [int]$strYear = $strYear

        Write-host ($strDay)
        Write-host ($strMonth)
        Write-host ($strYear)
        
        #these scripts are NOT working in the server
        $sQry = "SELECT Id, QuoteId, CreateTime, XML FROM dbo.QuoteUpload "
        $sQryWhere = "WHERE day(CreateTime) =" + [int]$strDay +" and month(CreateTime) = " +[int]$strMonth +" and year(CreateTime) = "+ [int]$strYear
        
        $sQry =$sQry + $sQryWhere
        Write-host ($sQry)

        $cmd.CommandText = $sQry
         Write-host ("3")
        $cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
        Write-host ("4")
        $scon.Open()
        Write-host ("5")
        $adp = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $cmd
        $data = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
        $adp.Fill($data) | Out-Null
        $data.Tables[0]
       
        #logs
        $dtTime = Get-Date -UFormat "%m%d%Y"
        $logfname = "PSDownloadXMLViaSQL_" + $dtTime + ".log"
        $logfnameloc ="C:\sharepointfilesXML\Logs\" + $logfname

        if (Test-Path -Path "C:\sharepointfilesXML\Logs\") {
            if (-NOT(Test-Path -Path $logfnameloc)) {
                New-Item -itemType File -Path $logfnameloc
            }
        }else { 
            New-Item -Path "C:\sharepointfilesXML\Logs\" -ItemType Directory
            if (-NOT(Test-Path -Path $logfnameloc)) {
                New-Item -itemType File -Path $logfnameloc
            }
        }


        Write-host ("")
        Write-host -f DarkYellow "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
        Write-host ("")
        [int]$intFileCount = 0

        for($i=0;$i -lt $data.Tables[0].Rows.Count;$i++)
        { 
          #0 - ID
          #1 - CRMQuoteID
          #2 - CreateTime
          #3 - XML
          #4 - FileName

          $intFileCount = $intFileCount + 1
          $sDate = $($data.Tables[0].Rows[$i][2]).ToString("yyyyMMdd")
          Export-XML -sCRMQuoteID $($data.Tables[0].Rows[$i][1]) -sDate $sDate -sXML $($data.Tables[0].Rows[$i][3])
          
        }

        #summarized the record counts
        if ([int]$intFileCount -eq 0) {
            Write-host -f Red "No yesterdays record found."
            Write-host ("")
            #log the error
            $dtTime = Get-Date -UFormat "%m%d%Y_%T"
            $strLogs =  $dtTime   + "_Error: " + "No yesterdays record found."
            Add-Content -Path $logfnameloc -Value ($strLogs) -PassThru

        }else
        {
            Write-host -f Green "$intFileCount yesterdays record found..."
            Write-host ("")
            #log it
            $dtTime = Get-Date -UFormat "%m%d%Y_%T"
            $strLogs =  $dtTime   + "_ " + $intFileCount + " yesterdays record found."
            Add-Content -Path $logfnameloc -Value ($strLogs) -PassThru
        }

        $scon.Dispose()
        $cmd.Dispose()
    }
}


Function Export-XML {
    Param(
        [string]$sCRMQuoteID,
        [string]$sDate,
        [string]$sXML
    )
    Process
    {
        #write-host $sCRMQuoteID
        #write-host $sDate
        #write-host $sXML

        $path = "C:\sharepointfilesXML\"
        If(!(test-path $path))
        {
              New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $path
        }

        $sXMLFilename = $sCRMQuoteID + "_" + $sDate +".xml"
        Write-host -f Cyan $intFileCount "Processing file: " $sXMLFilename"..."

        #log it
        $dtTime = Get-Date -UFormat "%m%d%Y_%T"
        $strLogs =  $dtTime  + "_" + $intFileCount + ".Processing file: " + $sXMLFilename + "..."
        Add-Content -Path $logfnameloc -Value ($strLogs) -PassThru


        $sXMLLocation = "C:\sharepointfilesXML\" + $sXMLFilename
        New-Item $sXMLLocation -ItemType File
        Set-Content $sXMLLocation $sXML
        Write-host -f Green "XML file exported successfully: '$sXMLLocation'"
        Write-host ("")

        #log it
        $dtTime = Get-Date -UFormat "%m%d%Y_%T"
        $strLogs =  $dtTime   + "_XML file: " + $sXMLLocation + " has been exported successfully."
        Add-Content -Path $logfnameloc -Value ($strLogs) -PassThru


    }
}


#prod connection - testing success
#Execute-SQL -sconstring "Data Source=ussrva7003.gslb.rockwellautomation.com,1637;Initial Catalog=RAMCCQUOTE;User Id=svc_mcc_quote_service;Password=FNfAAr4t;Connection Timeout=0;Integrated Security=false"

#test connection - testing success
Execute-SQL -sconstring "Data Source=localhost\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=PSDatabase;Connection Timeout=0;Integrated Security=true"


Read-Host -Prompt “Press Enter to exit”
```

---

Comment: "Yesterday" in SQL Server is DATEADD(day, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS date))

Comment: @JonTout yes, you're correct but when I put that SQL script inside the PowerShell script it is not working...  It just gets stucked when powershell tries to open the connection.

Comment: has the connection closed properly since the script last ran?

Comment: @JonTout yes Jon, see my full code in my post.